# Javascript counting

Tags: javascript, counting

Code below is correct. But it doesn't work in my browser.
I have no clue why my browser isn't counting.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}

function minus(){
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
}
</SCRIPT>

<div id="input_div">
    <input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the script is running there are no elements as they haven't loaded yet.
Easy fix would be to just move the script to the bottom:

```
<div id="input_div">
    <input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count"); // now this is available

function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}

function minus(){
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
}
</script>
```

Comment: typo `<script type="text/javascrip">`

Comment: @Stuart - Oops, fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it u have to small errors in ur code. First u try to search for an element before it's in the dom. So this "document.getElementById("count")" will not return the element.

The other part is for a onclick to work u should ad a ";" after the function name like this.

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus();">
```

But then the element still wont get updated by clicking the button. So therefore u should include the script and rewrite it like this. What I have done is binding the onclick event on the element in the javascript at the same time as I create the function. I also changed so the variables are declared with one var and the code is wrapped in a self executing function so nothing is declared in the global scope. I hope my answer helped u some, good luck!

HTML

```
<div id="input_div">
    <input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="moins">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="plus"">
</div>
<script>
(function(document){
var count = 0,
    countEl = document.getElementById("count"),
    minus = document.getElementById("moins"),
    plus = document.getElementById("plus");   
plus.onclick = function(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}
minus.onclick = function(){
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
}
}(document));
</script>
```

Here is a link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mU8sW/) to test the code.